# Cannot associate Categories and posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm making blog with http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PUHmX18Zmyk video.
my Post model is

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :body, :publish_date, :title, :user_id
  validates_presence_of :title, :body, :publish_date, :user_id
  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end
```

Category model is

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  validates_presence_of :name
  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
end
```

In video he used such code to generate list of categories in new post

```
<%  f.association :categories, :as => :checkboxes %>
```

But i have error

```
undefined method `association' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0xb5e82b40>
```

What is the right way to make the list of categories?

Comment: Are you using the simple_form gem? If not, the `f.association` method is not available in your form builder. If you are, check to make sure that you're calling `simple_form_for` not just `form_for`

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the rails docs to make a select box, that will allow you to select the category name, but send the category_id with the post.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#making-select-boxes-with-ease